# Oracle - TYPE TABLE - Collection Method EXISTS in IF Statement - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: erro: character to number conversion error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle11gr2, generic-collections

I need to make a collection in a Package, but I don't know where was the mistake...

This is my declaration and initialization:

```
avversao varchar2(30);
TYPE tListaVersaoHomologada IS TABLE OF NVARCHAR2(30);
vVersaoHomologada tListaVersaoHomologada := tListaVersaoHomologada('0.06', '0.07');
```

And this is where raise the exception

```
if NOT(vVersaoHomologada.EXISTS(avversao)) then
        ...
end if;
```

The variable

```
avversao
```

Have one of the values:

- 0.06
- 0.07

Reference:

[Using PL/SQL Collections and Records](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm)

[Collection Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collection_method.htm)

Comment: Why do you use `NVARCHAR2` for number values?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit is not my code, but I suppose because the localization/regional definition... that code is written in a country where the decimal separator is a comma, not a dot. Did the Oracle always consider the decimal separator as a comma?

Comment: Decimal separator is governed by NLS settings. The defaults are American but it's easy enough to set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARCTERS to whatever you need

Comment: If this is because the localization/regional definition then it would be even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`member of` - checking if value exists in collection.
`EXISTS` - Is for check if collection has value in index.

```
declare 
avversao varchar2(30) := '0.06';
TYPE tListaVersaoHomologada IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
vVersaoHomologada tListaVersaoHomologada := tListaVersaoHomologada('0.06', '0.07');
begin

 if avversao member of vVersaoHomologada then 
  dbms_output.put_line('!!!!Exist!!!!!');
 end if; 

end;
```